# Neo4j: Customize Path Traversal

Tags: neo4j

I am pretty new to Neo4j. I have implemented an example use case with the following setup:

- acyclic directed graph
- nodes have a property called externalID
- Nodes:

  - Node Type S (Start Node)
  - Node Type E (End Node)
  - Node Type I (Intermediate Node)
- Relations:

  - Node Type S can only have outgoing relations to Nodes of Type I
  - Node Type I can have ingoing relations from I and S
  - Node Type I can have outgoing relations to I and E
  - Node Type E can only have incomming relations from I
  - All relations have a weight property assigned which can be any number

With the help of stackoverflow and several tutorials I was able to formulate a Cypher query which gets me all paths from any start node with one externalID to the matching end node with the same externalID.

```
MATCH p=(a:S)-[r*]->(b:E) 
WHERE a.externalID=b.externalID
WITH p, relationships(p) as rcoll 
RETURN p
```

The query works more or less good so far ...

However, I have no idea how to change the behavior on how the graph is scanned for possible paths. Actually I only need a subset of all possible paths. Such paths fulfill the following requirement:

- The path traversal is started at a Start Node S with a given capacity C.
- if a relationship is traversed the weight property of this relationship is subtracted from the current capacity C (that means negative weights are added)

  - if the capacity gets negative the path up to this point is invalid (the path up to the previous node is still valid and may continue with other relationships)
  - if the capacity is still positive continue with another relationship from this point and use the result of C - weight as new C

Can I somehow adjust the query or is there any other possibility with Neo4j to get all paths using the strategy above?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming that paths where the capacity goes negative, but then becomes positive again later, is invalid, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You may want to check out the [traversal framework](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal) for these kind of queries. The Cypher equivalent seems like it will be rather tricky to construct.

Comment: Is your graph made up of disconnected subgraphs per start node, or is it one large interconnected graph? For all paths through an :I node, is there only one start node, or possibly multiple?

Comment: The graph is interconnected. A node :I may be reachable from different start nodes. Thank you for the hint on the traversal framework. It looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Cypher query might be suitable for your use case:

```
MATCH p = (a:S)-[r*]->(b:E) 
WHERE a.externalID = b.externalID
WITH
  p,
  REDUCE(c = a.capacity, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) |
    CASE WHEN c < 0 THEN -1 ELSE c - r.weight END) AS residual
WHERE residual >= 0
RETURN p;
```

The `REDUCE` clause will set `residual` to a negative value if the capacity is ever reduced below `0`, even if subsequent weights would normally cause it to go positive.

Comment: Even though I am right now using the Traversal framework as a solution I am going to mark this answer as correct as the solution works. I think the traversal framework solution is better in terms of performance as this Cypher query will find all paths and filters at the end whereas with the traversal framework approach I can make the traversal stop directly at the transition where the capacity condition fails. Thanks for the effort anyway. The solution is also nice.